# HTML make an input object, onClick=" " event, go to the hostname of the current website (go to root of domain)

Tags: html, input, onclick, onmouseover, hostname

I am trying to make this code below to take the current window to the root of the domain.

say if you are on `http://www.example.com/myprofile/status/…` if you click on the image in the code, it will take you to the root or host name, being `http://www.example.com`.

i have tried many ways to make this work, way too many ways to list them all. it has to be possible some how. please help me out.

```
<input onmouseover='this.src="board-button_acti… 
onmouseout='this.src="board-button.png"'
name="submit" 
border="0" 
type="image" src="board-button.png" alt="Board Index" value="Board Index" onclick="window.location.hostname">
```

what you want to look at in this code is the very last part, titled `onclick="window.location.hostname"`

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="location.href= '/'; return false;"
```

(Returning `false` to stop the form from being submitted, which could lead to inconsistent results on which navigation succeeds.) You can also write to `location.pathname` to change the path without changing host, though navigating to a relative URL is just as effective.

However, I'd suggest that if you have a button that takes you to a different page, what you actually have here is a link. It would be much more appropriate, and better-behaving, to mark it up as a simple `<a href="/">`. You can use CSS to style it so it looks like a button if you prefer.

```
<input onmouseover='this.src="board-button...
```

`input type="submit"` has no `src` so this won't do anything. Use CSS `:hover` styling to get mouse-over effects.

Comment: can you write out how i would use the css to solve this? this might solve it.

Comment: `<a class="buttonlike" href="/">Board index</a>` then styling is up to you to decide. As a basic start, try `.buttonlike { color: black; background: silver; border: outset silver 2px; padding: 2px; text-decoration: none; }`, but you can get as elaborate as you like with background images or newer CSS3 fun like `border-radius` and `linear-gradient`.

Comment: A common approach is to use a fixed-size background-image to get the exact rendering you want. However since you can't set width/height on an inline element, you have to turn it into a `display: block` or `inline-block` for that.

Answer (score 0):

with your guy's help i answered the issue.

i added a href around the input, and just got rid of the onclick

here is the output, and it works!

```
<a href="/">
<input onmouseover='this.src="board-button_acti… 
onmouseout='this.src="board-button.png"'
name="submit" 
border="0" 
type="image" src="board-button.png" alt="Board Index" value="Board Index" />
</a>
```

Comment: Why not use an `img` element instead of an `input` element?